How to filter Sentry errors that did originated from the bundle loaded via script tag
I am working on a plugin that is loaded via script tag on the page. I host the source code of this bundle in the CDN.
I dynamically load the Sentry via temporarily creating the script tag with the Sentry loader.js from the CDN.
My issue is that once its loaded, I am receiving all the error from the page where the plugin bundle was loaded.
How can I filter is so that I only receive errors for this bundle?
